# Sphero Locator: how to improve precision

Tags: javascript, position, sphero-api

I'm developing a spheroApp quiz. Practically it's a quiz game where it's possible to answer question driving sphero to one of 3 hole that define the answer.

Well, i use locator to define position of sphero. In the wizard section it's possible to define the 3 hole position driving from a single start position (0,0).

I save the 3 hole position and when the sphero go in (i have defined a gap between 10/20 from position of the hole) the app discover that it's a right/wrong answer.

but, every time i try to go in the same position i receive from sphero different coordinates.

there is some method used to improve the precision of locator?

If someone know something about let me know!

thanks ;)

ps:
i have followed this guide!
https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/Locator#the-default-setup
tnx

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different things here that I think might be the issue. Unfortunately, the locator is not crazy accurate to begin with, as the data is pulled from the motors taking the ball places. I was discussing with a couple guys here, and we surmise that if you were to put the ball in the center, and then drive it towards what the vertex points of an equilateral triangle that that would probably work best. The other issue that might be getting you is calibration. When you calibrate the ball, the heading is reset and therefore the locator thinks that it is moving in a different direction than it actually is. Perhaps in you app you will need to have some calibration for your gap detection when the ball calibrates to keep everything in sync.

Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: First of All thanks for your Answer! ;)

in my app everytime I save a position I come back to original position(drive ball to the position, not through a marco) and send a ResetLocation (RKConfigureLocatorCommand with all to 0 and flag = 1).

Did I understood what you mean?

Comment: When resetting that you might be contaminating your results by resetting your heading, unless the ball is aimed in the same way that is was before you selected an answer. What you would need to do is drive the ball back, aim it to the same spot each time, then run that command to configure the locator. That should help.